# Two threads accessing same variables, but one thread rarely happens. Non-atomics?

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86, atomic, memory-fences

I have two threads, t1 and t2, which access several variables (ints and doubles), lets call them a, b and c. t1 is on my critical path and increments/decrements these variables via an expensive compare-and-exchange.

```
std::atomic<double> a;
std::atomic<double> b;
std::atomic<double> c;
std::atomic<uint32_t> d;
.
.
.
// Extremely-common, critical path thread t1
d++;
while(!a.compare_and_exchange(expectedVal, newVal);
while(!b.compare_and_exchange(expectedVal, newVal);
while(!c.compare_and_exchange(expectedVal, newVal);
```

t2 rarely occurs but when it does, it adds the variables mentioned above together.

```
// Rare thread, t2
return a + b - c;
```

At the moment I use atomics. **Is there any way I can declare the variables as non-atomic, because 99.999% of the time they are incremented from the same thread and on the "rare thread" I could use a memory barrier to ensure I cannot return `a + b - c` until the "critical path" thread has finished writing any stores?**

This would allow me to add the latency only on the occasional situation the rare thread executes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from your question if this is possible, but you might be able to refactor the "communication" between your threads to share less state.

E.g., suppose they only "communicate" via `a + b - c`, in the sense that only t1 updates the components individually, and t2 only reads this particular combination. In this case, you could use fewer atomic ops by defining `a`, `b`, and `c` as regular variables, and a new variable, `combination`, as an atomic variable. t1 would then increment stuff normally, and would use a single atomic op to update `combination`.

Comment: So basically keep the result cached and t1 updates that cached result?

Comment: Sounds right. Is there anything particular you have a question about?

Comment: Yup, but that's not much of an issue, no? t2 is out of the critical path anyway, according to the question.

Comment: Actually, as soon as you have single point of communication, you MAY be able to avoid atomics at all; the thing is that properly aligned data is always read and written atomically, even without CAS, so if this is indeed the only point of communication between threads (i.e. there are no other variables of similar nature) - then within t2 you won't be able to distinguish if you've read "old" data just because t2 asked for it before t1 has put it there, or because t2 asked for it after the t1 has put it there, but before data has propagated to t2.

Comment: @No-Bugs Hare You may be right, but I'm not quite sure. Having read Anthony William's book on threading in C++11 some time ago, I think that there might be a problem of partial reads.

Comment: If I remember correctly, atomicity of reads on aligned data is guaranteed even in RMO, and certainly in TSO memory model. In general, it has nothing to do with C++, it is all about guarantees provided by underlying hardware. The risk with such non-synchronized access is about one piece of data (D1) written by t1 earlier than another piece of data (D2), but D2 becoming visible to t2 earlier than D1 - and this needs to be resolved by memory barriers - but if there is no D2, then there is no problem :-).

Comment: I'm not sure if swapping the three variables for the one atomic would reduce latency from making the atomic operations (it would save object space in the cache though). Instead of incrementing three atomic variables, I would just be incrementing one atomic variable three times- which is effectively the same. I was hoping to find a way of allowing the cached variable to be non-atomic and force the rare thread to read the non-atomic variable, atomically (through using memory barriers). Is there no way I can force all operations on the cached variable to finish, before t2 reads it?